# Extract section from URL path

Tags: python

Any comments / improvements welcome on this simple function.

tests.py

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize([
    # path
    '/c/target-uri',
    '/c/uk/indiana/target-uri',
    '/c/uk/indiana/target-uri/persons',
    '/c/uk/florida/target-uri/persons',
])
def test_extract_uri(self, path):
    assert extract_uri(path) == 'target-uri'
```

main.py

```
from states import state_names


def extract_uri(path: str):
    exclude_path_snippets = ['persons']

    def filter_fn(element: str):
        return all([
            element.lower() not in state_names,
            element.lower() not in exclude_path_snippets,
            len(element) > 2,  # exclude 'c' or 'uk'
        ])

    path_snippets: List[str] = path.split('/')
    filtered = list(filter(filter_fn, path_snippets))

    if len(filtered) != 1:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to extract uri from {path}")

    return filtered[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter_fn` should probably be moved to a global because it does not need closure.

Combine `state_names` and `exclude_path_snippets` to one set via `|`, and then reduce to a single `not in`.

`all` is not called-for; use a single boolean expression. Once you have only one set comparison, you will only need one `and`.

Don't raise a bare `Exception`. Raise a `ValueError`, or an application-specific exception.

Consider a tuple-unpack, potentially with a rethrow; and don't cast to a `list`:

```
try:
    filtered, = filter(filter_fn, path_snippets)
except ValueError as e:
    raise ValueError(f'Failed to extract URI from {path}') from e
return filtered
```

`filter_fn` deserves a better name like `is_snippet_valid`.

Comment: `filter_fn` doesn't need closure, but arguably doesn't need to be polluting the global namespace - is that an argument for using an inner function?

Comment: @TobySpeight IMO no. Global functions are more easily unit-testable, and module exports can still be managed via `__all__`

Answer (score 6):

Your tests are not very robust.

Consider the following implementation

```
def extract_uri(path: str):
    return 'target-uri'
```

Is this the wrong implementation if it passes all your tests? Either both the implementation and the tests are ok, or neither is.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the `filter_fn` function by using a list comprehension and an `any()` call:

```
def test_extract_uri(self, path):
    def filter_fn(element: str):
        return [
            element.lower() not in state_names,
            element.lower() not in exclude_path_snippets,
            len(element) > 2,  # exclude 'c' or 'uk'
        ]

    path_snippets: List[str] = path.split('/')
    filtered = list(filter(filter_fn, path_snippets))

    if len(filtered) != 1:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to extract uri from {path}")

    return filtered[0]
```

Alternatively, we can use a regular expression to extract the target URI from the path. This would make the code more readable and maintainable:

```
import re

def test_extract_uri(self, path):
    match = re.match(r'/c(?:/[a-zA-Z]{2})?/[a-zA-Z]+/target-uri(?:/persons)?', path)
    if not match:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to extract uri from {path}")
    return match.group(0)
```

It's also a good idea to import the `List` type from the `typing` module and add type hints to the `extract_uri()` and `test_extract_uri()` functions. Finally, it's a good practice to add a docstring explaining what the function does and what its input and output are.